# Completed column is missing in my task list view - checkbox

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, library

What I'm trying to accomplish; checkbox that show if a task is "done / finished"

[image]

But when I try to edit the library view I only get "% Complete" and not "Completed". Is there some settings I'm missing? 
[image]

Do I have to create my own site column to get this functionality?

**Solution**

I found that I'm adding wrong list.

```
var list = web.Lists;
lists.Add(TasksListNameListName, "", SPListTemplateType.Tasks);
```

I should have used `TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy` insted of `Tasks`! Then you get the checkbox out-of-the-box :)

```
var list = web.Lists;
lists.Add(TasksListNameListName, "", SPListTemplateType.TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy);
```

Comment: what Kind of view are you trying to build?

Comment: Like in the first picture, with the site columns "task nr", "completed" (checkbox), title...

Comment: No I mean are you trying a Standart-View or Data View etc.?

Comment: I'm using standard-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I'm adding wrong list template.

```
var list = web.Lists;
lists.Add(TasksListNameListName, "", SPListTemplateType.Tasks);
```

I should have used `TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy` insted of `Tasks`! Then you get the checkbox out-of-the-box :)

```
var list = web.Lists;
lists.Add(TasksListNameListName, "", SPListTemplateType.TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the view to Basic style.. then reset them back to "Default" ?

It did the trick for our environment.

And also make sure you have applied the latest Microsoft SharePoint patches. 
Otherwise I think the problem is that check boxes don't show up on the view . Why don't you make the column drop down list with to option Completed or not and I am sure it will show up on view.

Comment: I'm provisioning all team sites based on a approver list with web templates. So then I have to make it problematically

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this column is missing in your view editor, but you could just make a new column as a calculated field with formula `=[% Complete]>=1` (like in the original one) and return type is yes/no.

Can you try that and look if this column would appear in your list view Editor?